# Testing python float range sizes

Tags: python-3.x

Hey there StackOverflow!  I have what I'm hoping is a simple problem and I was wanting to see if there was a more simple way to go about this.  So I have a I have a data structure to where I have a bunch of numeric ranges.  These ranges are relational values between sensors.  Here is an example

```
data1 = {
    'sensor01': {'bucket': [1, 4], 'offline_count': 103},
    'sensor04': {'bucket': [1.19, 2.24], 'offline_count': 32},
    'sensor05': {'bucket': [3.19, 4.24], 'offline_count': 32},
    'sensor06': {'bucket': [-1.16, 4.25], 'offline_count': 161},
    'sensor07': {'bucket': [2.494331, 9.320493], 'offline_count': 203},
}

data2 = {
    'sensor01': {'bucket': [3, 5], 'offline_count': 103},
    'sensor04': {'bucket': [0.19, 1.25], 'offline_count': 32},
    'sensor05': {'bucket': [4.19, 5.24], 'offline_count': 32},
    'sensor06': {'bucket': [-2.16, 0.25], 'offline_count': 161},
    'sensor07': {'bucket': [12.272427, 18.69733], 'offline_count': 203},
}
```

The values of the sensor are, or can be simply represented as floats with various levels of precision.  The problem I have is that I need to test these ranges to determine the smallest possible range for any given point in time. This is more or less simple in Python to do in a very inefficient way:

```
for k, v in data1.items():
    d1_range = range(int(data1[k]['bucket'][0] * 1000), int(data1[k]['bucket'][1]) * 1000)
    d2_range = range(int(data2[k]['bucket'][0] * 1000), int(data2[k]['bucket'][0]) * 1000)
    if len(d1_range) < len(d2_range):
        print("data1 range smaller")
    else:
        print("data2 range smaller")
```

While this does work I'm left wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.  It seems like multiplying out the float and using len on a range object seems like a lot of processing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can omit range(), just use the diffrrence, or absolute value of a difference to get the distance. Also you can zip() two of your list together for easier access + write a separate finction for repeated code in your sample code.

Comment: Nitpick: you aren't using `len` on a generator. You are using it on a `range` object. This is quite efficient, and spares you the simple arithmetic.

Comment: Technically range is a generator I think,  but it's not a generator expression.

Comment: but I guess I see the point of len() is probably calling the __len__() on the range object... I guess this is why English isn't suitable for a programming language =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute value of the difference of the maximum and minimum values to get the range:

```
for k,v in data1.items():
  b1 = data1[k]['bucket']
  b2 = data2[k]['bucket']
  d1 = abs(b1[1] - b1[0])
  d2 = abs(b2[1] - b2[0])
  if d1 < d2:
    print("data1 range smaller")
  else:
    print("data2 range smaller")
```

Comment: That is much more simple, Thanks!  I had the feeling I was just missing some thing simple...